Forward and backward reasoning completeness
Proof assistants can consist of both forward and backward tactics. I have several questions in regards to this below which I would be grateful if someone had answers to.

Is it correct that if only forward tactics are applied, that's akin to a "direct proof" in standard mathematics?
Is by_contradiction (in Lean) for example a backward tactic and does proof by contradiction require a backward tactic like that or is there a way to do it using only forward tactics?
If proof by contradiction requires backward tactics, then does that we cannot write all possible proofs in Lean using just forward tactics?
Is it possible to write any proof in proof assistants using just backward tactics or are forward tactics necessary?

Thanks!

You can write any proof using only forward reasoning, or only backward reasoning. Both methods are popular in the literature, for example in automated theorem proving forward reasoning is called "saturation" and backward reasoning is "tableau methods". Backward reasoning generally requires you to specify less about the subgoals, which makes it convenient in a setting like Lean's.
A forward reasoning version of by-contradiction would be: First, construct a proof of $\neg\neg P$. Therefore $P$ holds "by contradiction".
In Lean's underlying type theory, all proofs are expressed as proof terms, and you can read these terms as constructing a direct (forward) proof. By-contradiction is the theorem Classical.byContra : ∀ P, ¬¬P → P, which you apply in the forward direction by supplying the statement P you want to use and the proof of ¬¬P, and you get a proof of P. The fact that the P you supply also happens to be the conclusion of the theorem probably contributes to your impression that this can only be used in the backward direction, but there isn't really anything special about this theorem from Lean's perspective, it does the same kind of instantiation regardless of whether the goal is P or some other expression containing P or other things.

Thanks for the response. Is there a way to convert the Lean proof terms into a sequence of forward tactics?

Same question as above comment but also for a sequence of backward tactics

Yes, there is a way to do it, but you won't like the result. You should explain why you are asking these questions. What's the motive?

@AndrejBauer Hmm why will I not like the result? The motivation is to generate additional data for training a machine learning model on Lean code.

@AndrejBauer To be clear, I'm looking for an automated way to do the translation as I want to do it on a large scale

You can just take the formal proof and convert it to a really silly looking sequence of tactics steps, either forward style (by generating the tactics bottom-up), or backward style (by a top-down approach).

@AndrejBauer If one goes off a proof that uses backward tactics, how would one map each backward tactic to a forward one automatically tho? (Same question if we're going off proof terms)

@Opt The only difference is that forward proof steps add facts to the context and refer to each other by name, while backward proof steps traverse the term in preorder, with each tactic producing subgoals for the following. They are two valid serializations of the same tree data structure (the proof term).
